# Is it safe to store the activity references in savedinstancestate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-sqlite

in my application, i have kept a controller class & this is a singleton class. I use this class to fetch the data from first activity, or store some of the information which is required for remaining activities in my app. Even sometime i require to access First activity method from last activity also. At this time, this controller comes to help.

The problem comes when user press homebutton, if a user press home button, and resumed after sometime or after opening several other applications, app crashes.

I got to know that issue is because, activity references wont be existing in controller. So, whenever user press homebutton can i save all these instances & use it once user resume?.

Even i have fragments in one activity, does those references also needs to be saved?

How to handle thse senarios?, any help

Answer (score 0):

> So, whenever user press homebutton can i save all these instances &
>   use it once user resume?.

The "instances" aren't removed when you press home. They are removed when the app is in the background and Android needs more memory some time later (might never happen).

> Is it safe to store the activity references in savedinstancestate

Yes this is what [saved instance state was made for](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

> As your activity begins to stop, the system calls
>   onSaveInstanceState() so your activity can save state information with
>   a collection of key-value pairs. The default implementation of this
>   method saves information about the state of the activity's view
>   hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll
>   position of a ListView.

.

> can i save all these instances?

You can't save the instances - you will have to store the information that you will use to re-build your activity as key-value pairs. What I do is I store just enough information so that the activity can rebuild itself.

For example, if the Activity has a list that was constructed from api.myapp.com, I will save this URL, as well as the scroll location of the list. The rest you should probably go retrieve again as if you had just launched the app for the first time - this will make your code much simpler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. my question is, according to my design i have got few activity references, database references are created and accessed from controller. So, if i press home button these object present in static class will get vanishes, so is it safe to store the object references in  onSaveInstanceState() class.

Comment: Also one more query. If i remove controller from my class, how do i get reference to first activity from 3rd activity. Assume A, B, C are activity, how do i access method of A activity from C?. is controller class really necessary to develop apps?

Comment: You cannot store object references. You can only store `ints`, `strings` etc. You will need to store the most fundamental information, and then completely recreate all your objects from scratch when you relaunch the app (first check if the references point to null - they might not)

Comment: But, in my case i have a static class i.e controller holds references to activity, so how to store controller class then?. so in this case i have to remove controller?. Also can u pls tell Assume A, B, C are activity, how do i access method of A activity from C?

Comment: System architecture is hard to explain in a comment box. But you do not want to have Activities accessing each other's methods. The method of Activity A should only be used when Activity A is running. If you want shared methods, factor them out to a common class.

Comment: Ok, common class is only the controller in my case. So i m worried how to save the object references of activity in controller. via controller i use to access the method. I.e A, B, C are activity controller class, hold A reference, From C, i use to call controller, via controller A's method i use to access. So here i m loosing A reference if i press home button and come back